Looking for references/resources to help explain why a design is pseudoreplicated to a colleague
A colleague and I are working on a project which involves sampling 15 different sites, and we collected 3 replicate samples at each site (to capture spatial variability, not repeated measures at an exact location). Each site falls into one of three groups (A, B, or C), and we're interested in testing whether the mean value of some variable differs among sites--a classic one way ANOVA approach. The design is unbalanced (n = 4 sites for groups A & B, n = 7 sites for group C), but that's not the issue. I've raised the issue that treating each replicate as independent and conducting an ANOVA on 45 individual samples would be pseudoreplication, and we shouldn't do that. Instead, we should be using the means of the 3 replicates within each site in our ANOVA; thus, we would have 15 sample points grouped according to the sample sizes mentioned above. Unfortunately, some scientists have still never heard of pseudoreplication, and my concern was brushed off and analyses proceeded on the full set of 45 samples. I'd like to come back with some proper material to back up my claim and proceed to do the analysis appropriately before I continue working on the project.
Are there some classic or well-received references or resources that provide a similar example, explaining why this is pseudoreplication and the appropriate way to approach ANOVA in this case? I've found some pertaining more to medical studies, which is fine, but I'm hoping for more of a field biology/ecology context.
I welcome any explanations and/or suggestions from the community as well.
